# Java/Swing/Maven: no main manifest attribute

Tags: java, swing, maven-plugin

When I'm in NetBeans environment, I run my Jasper report normally. But when I try the command line:

```
java -jar C: \ ... \ mySwingProject.jar
```

I am getting the following error message:

> no main manifest attribute in C: \ ... \ mySwingProject.jar

My pom.xml follows:

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
  xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
  <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

  <groupId>br.jus.tjmg</groupId>
  <artifactId>RhServidoresDesligados</artifactId>
  <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
  <packaging>jar</packaging>

  <name>RhServidoresDesligados</name>
  <url>http://maven.apache.org</url>
    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.3.2</version>
                <configuration>
                  <archive>
                    <manifest>
                      <mainClass>br.jus.tjmg.rhservidoresdesligados.JFramePrincipal</mainClass>
                    </manifest>
                  </archive>                  
                    <source>1.7</source>
                    <target>1.7</target>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>
    <repositories>
    <repository>
      <url>http://download.eclipse.org/rt/eclipselink/maven.repo/</url>
      <id>eclipselink</id>
      <layout>default</layout>
      <name>Repository for library EclipseLink (JPA 2.1)</name>
    </repository>
  </repositories>
  <properties>
    <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
  </properties>

  <dependencies>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>junit</groupId>
      <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
      <version>3.8.1</version>
      <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.eclipse.persistence</groupId>
      <artifactId>javax.persistence</artifactId>
      <version>2.1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>net.sf.jasperreports</groupId>
      <artifactId>jasperreports</artifactId>
      <version>6.1.0</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.eclipse.persistence</groupId>
      <artifactId>eclipselink</artifactId>
      <version>2.5.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.eclipse.persistence</groupId>
      <artifactId>org.eclipse.persistence.jpa.modelgen.processor</artifactId>
      <version>2.5.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
      <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>log4j</groupId>
      <artifactId>log4j</artifactId>
      <version>1.2.17</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>com.oracle</groupId>
      <artifactId>ojdbc7</artifactId>
      <version>11.2.0</version>
    </dependency>    
  </dependencies>
</project>
```

What could be wrong?

Answer (score 1):

To create executable jar file use [maven-jar-plugin](http://maven.apache.org/shared/maven-archiver/examples/classpath.html) instead. Seems you mistyped.

```
<plugin>
    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
    <artifactId>maven-jar-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>2.6</version>
    <configuration>
        <archive>
            <manifest>
                <addClasspath>true</addClasspath>
                <mainClass>br.jus.tjmg.rhservidoresdesligados.JFramePrincipal</mainClass>
            </manifest>
        </archive>
    </configuration>
</plugin>
```

Answer (score 0):

Works fine! 'artifactId' tag value was incorrect!

Comment: You can [answer your own question](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/17463/163188), but please edit your answer to illustrate the correct value.